# Getting few results with trying to authenticate and search repositories with github API using python

Tags: python, api, rest, github, github-api

I'm trying to search for repositories using javascript using python and the github API, and put the links to the repositories in a file.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint
username = #my username here!
token = #my token here!

user_data = requests.get(f"https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:js&sort=stars&order=desc", auth=(username,token)).json()

headers = {'Authorization': 'token ' + token}

login = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', headers=headers)
print(login.json())
f = open("snapshotJS.txt", "w")
for userKeys in user_data.keys():
    if userKeys == "items":
        for item in user_data[userKeys]:
            for lines in item:
                if lines == "html_url":
                    print(item.get(lines))
                    f.write(item.get(lines) + "\n")
f.close()
```

When I run the code, I only get 30 links in my textfile every time (granted, they're different links every time I run it). How would I be able to get more than 30 at a time? Since I have a personal token, shouldn't I be able to get up to 5000 requests?

Sorry if it's something small I'm missing, I'm new to API!

Answer (score 0):

The Github API returns 30 entries per page if the size of the page is not specified.

> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the page parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the per_page parameter.

To get more records in a page, use the `per_page` query param.

To get all the records, use a while loop to keep fetching the pages till no page is left.

Comment: thank you, this is helpful! how can you tell which page number you're on in order to iterate properly? I'm trying to make the loop

Comment: I didn't got the question. For pagination you would have to start with page 0 (or page 1) and keep on incrementing the page number.